# Titanium Appcelerator manipulate image with additional text and other images

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

My question pertains to Titanium Appcelerator Mobile, I am looking to develop an app and looking for the best approach. I need to send an image as an email but I first want to manipulate the image but placing text or adding other pieces such as another image embedded. Can this be done? And what is thebest way to do so. Can I build it as an HTML page and then save as an image? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You could build an HTML page, and then store it to an image.

Webview has a function called `toImage`. You could use that.

Also take a look at the docs: http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.WebView-object

Include this in your HTML to make it fit to screen.

```
var html = '<html><head><meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width, height=device-height, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /></head><body>';
var webview = Ti.UI.createWebView({html: html});
var imageBlob = webview.toImage();
```